# How to override Material-UI Popover Paper styles?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Basically, i'm trying to override a style which is automatically introduce in my program. When i use Popover, automatically i have MuiPopover-paper styles in my program, i have to change some styles in this class, but how??

```css
.MuiPopover-paper {
    outline: none;
    position: absolute;
    max-width: calc(100% - 32px);
    min-width: 16px;
    max-height: calc(100% - 32px);
    min-height: 16px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

code part

const styles = (theme: Theme) => {
  return createStyles({
    notifications: {
      width: 449,
      height: 400,
      overflow: 'auto'
    },
    settings: {
      width: 300,
      height: 360
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: in your css , create .MuiPopover-paper class with !important for required properties, suppose if you want to change min-width, use .MuiPopover-paper { min-width: 20px !important;}

Comment: hey man, but how, i'm using typescript to do so .. i have this, how can i do what you tell?
```javascript
const styles = (theme: Theme) => {
  return createStyles({
    notifications: {
      width: 449,
      height: 400,
      overflow: 'auto'
    },
    settings: {
      width: 300,
      height: 360
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: add to createStyles({  .MuiPopover-paper { min-width: 20px !important;}

Comment: and then, i put in my Popover component like, className={classes.[".MuiPopover-paper"]} ? Because, i try this, and its not working

Comment: You can use another class for the Popover component Or you can use parent class to overwrite the CSS.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One of the ways to overwrite the style of a component is to use the rule name of the classes object prop. As you can see from the [MUI API documentation for Popover](https://material-ui.com/api/popover/), you can overwrite the styles applied to the Paper component:

```
    <Popover classes={{ paper: "MuiPopover-paper" }} />
```